# Webcodecs VideoDecoder undefined

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webcodecs

I tried to use webodecs in my react project. But it doesn't seem to work.

Here is my debug code:

```js
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
// import Editor from './components/pages/editor/editor';
import { useEffect } from 'react';

function App() {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(window.VideoDecoder);
  });

  return (
    <div></div>
    // <Editor/>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Then I opened `http://localhost:port/`, I got **ƒ VideoDecoder() { [native code] }** in console. But if I opened `http://ip:port/`, I would get **undefined** in console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [VideoDecoder interface](https://w3c.github.io/webcodecs/#videodecoder-interface) is only available in [secure contexts](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#secure-context)

```
[Exposed=(Window,DedicatedWorker), SecureContext]
```

You must serve your page from such a secure context, i.e from `https://` here.